# How do I get my .js file to render an .html file in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been trying to implement an S3 bucket on my website to store uploaded images to amazon's cloud. In order to do this, some HTML boiler-plate is required. I made an HTML file and copied boiler-plate and would like to utilize this on my .js file now, which contains the webpage where I would like this information to be displayed.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <h1>Edit your account</h1>

    <hr>

    <h2>Your avatar</h2>

    <input type="file" id="file-input">
    <p id="status">Please select a file</p>
    <img style="border:1px solid gray;width:300px;"  id="preview" src="/images/default.png">

    <h2>Your information</h2>

    <form method="POST" action="/save-details">
      <input type="hidden" id="avatar-url" name="avatar-url" value="/images/default.png">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
      <input type="text" name="full-name" placeholder="Full name"><br><br>

      <hr>
      <h2>Save changes</h2>

      <input type="submit" value="Update profile">
    </form>


    <script>

    /*
      Function to carry out the actual PUT request to S3 using the signed request from the app.
    */
    function uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url){
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            document.getElementById('preview').src = url;
            document.getElementById('avatar-url').value = url;
          }
          else{
            alert('Could not upload file.');
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.send(file);
    }

    /*
      Function to get the temporary signed request from the app.
      If request successful, continue to upload the file using this signed
      request.
    */
    function getSignedRequest(file){
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', `/sign-s3?file-name=${file.name}&file-type=${file.type}`);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            uploadFile(file, response.signedRequest, response.url);
          }
          else{
            alert('Could not get signed URL.');
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    }

    /*
     Function called when file input updated. If there is a file selected, then
     start upload procedure by asking for a signed request from the app.
    */
    function initUpload(){
      const files = document.getElementById('file-input').files;
      const file = files[0];
      if(file == null){
        return alert('No file selected.');
      }
      getSignedRequest(file);
    }

    /*
     Bind listeners when the page loads.
    */
    (() => {
        document.getElementById('file-input').onchange = initUpload;
    })();

    </script>

<div id="root"></div>

  </body>
```

Here is the .js file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Typography, Button, Form, message, Input, Icon } from "antd";
import FileUpload from "../../utils/FileUpload";
import FileUploadNew from "../../utils/fileUploadNew";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Axios from "axios";

const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;
const num = 20


const Continents = [
  { key: 1, value: "MLA" },
  { key: 2, value: "APA" },
];

function UploadProductPage(props) {
  const [TitleValue, setTitleValue] = useState("");
  const [SubjectValue, setSubjectValue] = useState("");
  const [DescriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState("");
  const [PriceValue, setPriceValue] = useState(0);
  const [ContinentValue, setContinentValue] = useState(1);
  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState("");


  const [Images, setImages] = useState("");

  const onTitleChange = (event) => {
    setTitleValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onSubjectChange = (event) => {
    setSubjectValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onDescriptionChange = (event) => {
    setDescriptionValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onPriceChange = (event) => {
    setPriceValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onContinentsSelectChange = (event) => {
    setContinentValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const updateImages = (newImages) => {
    setImages(newImages);
  };
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      !TitleValue ||
      !SubjectValue ||
      !DescriptionValue ||
      !PriceValue ||
      !ContinentValue ||
      !Images
    ) {
      return alert("fill all the fields first!");
    }

    const variables = {
      writer: props.user.userData._id,
      title: TitleValue,
      subject: SubjectValue,
      description: DescriptionValue,
      price: PriceValue,
      images: Images,
      continents: ContinentValue,
    };

      Axios.post("/api/product/uploadProduct", variables).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.success) {
        alert("Product Successfully Uploaded");
        
      } else {
        alert("Failed to upload Product");
      }
    });
  };
  const picData = (value) => {
    setImages(value);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: "700px", margin: "2rem auto" }}>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginBottom: "2rem" }}>
        <Title level={2}> Upload Prompt</Title>
      </div>

      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {/* DropZone */}
        {/* <FileUpload refreshFunction={updateImages} /> */}
        {/* kamran's code */}
        <FileUpload imagePath={picData} refreshFunction={updateImages} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Title</label>
        <Input onChange={onTitleChange} value={TitleValue} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Subject</label>
        <Input onChange={onSubjectChange} value={SubjectValue} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Description</label>
        <TextArea onChange={onDescriptionChange} value={DescriptionValue} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Number of pages</label>
        <Input onChange={onPriceChange} value={PriceValue} type="number" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Format</label>
        <br>
        </br>
        <select onChange={onContinentsSelectChange} value={ContinentValue}>
          {Continents.map((item) => (
            <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>
              {item.value}{" "}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />

        <Button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UploadProductPage;
```

I have been reading and trying to use getdocumentbyID but it's not working. No errors are being shown. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

React makes it easy to bind functions without having to select first then bind functions to the DOM.

Put your function above your return statement

```
  const picData = (value) => {
    setImages(value);
  };

  const uploadFile = (file, signedRequest, url) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        if(xhr.status === 200){
          document.getElementById('preview').src = url;
          document.getElementById('avatar-url').value = url;
        }
        else{
          alert('Could not upload file.');
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send(file);
  }

  const getSignedRequest = (file) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', `/sign-s3?file-name=${file.name}&file-type=${file.type}`);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        if(xhr.status === 200){
          const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          uploadFile(file, response.signedRequest, response.url);
        }
        else{
          alert('Could not get signed URL.');
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  }

  const initUpload = () => {
    const files = document.getElementById('file-input').files;
    const file = files[0];
    if(file == null){
      return alert('No file selected.');
    }
    getSignedRequest(file);
  }

return (
...rest of code here
```

In the DOM portion of your code, add the onChange to the input

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" onChange={initUpload}>
```

Comment: Thank you brother... this solved my problem. I marked your answer as helpful but still need higher reputation to show I think

Answer (score 0):

You can force React to render html by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as props in a component.

Here is a sample implementation:

`hello.html`

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

In your `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import hello from "./hello.html";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: hello }} />
    </div>
  );
```

In your case, import the html file just like a regular module by using `import htmlFile from './htmfile.html'` and write it in a `div` tag with `dangerouslySetInerHTML`

There's a reason on why it is considered *dangerous* to force React to render native .html file in your component. You may want to visit [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) to know more about div attributes and XSS.